# floatrow/subfigure - fit 7 figures in one page - caption as a subfigure

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption, floatrow

I am trying to put in one page a set of 7 subigures. What I would like to achieve is the following

1. The 7th image should be placed on the first column on the left hand side of the document (yellow box)
2. The figure caption should be place on the second column on the right hand side of the document, as if it was the 8th subfigure (blue ellipsis)
3. The subfigure letters should be placed below the images, on the center (red ellipses)<--- SOLVED

[image]

Any idea on how to do that?

My simple MWE is the following

```
\documentclass[aps,prc,reprint,superscriptaddress,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[pdftex, demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!80!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[]
    \centering
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\columnwidth]{CS_2n.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_2n}
        }
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\columnwidth]{CS_2n_m2.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_2n_m2}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\columnwidth]{CS_3n.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_3n}
        }
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\columnwidth]{CS_p.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_p}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\columnwidth]{CS_alpha.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_alpha}
        }
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\columnwidth]{CS_el.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_el}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\columnwidth]{CS_tot.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_tot}
        }\hfill
    %\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Blah blah blah}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Except it is a lot harder with floatrow.

Comment: @Zarko You are absolutely right! I will close the question! Sorry for the mess!

Comment: @JohnKormylo I guess you are right! Thanks!

Comment: You also need to fix \@makecaption, which will otherwise intercept the caption by floatrow.