# How to prevent floatrow from moving the caption?

Tags: captions, floatrow

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403533/floatrow-subfigure-fit-7-figures-in-one-page-caption-as-a-subfigure) the suggested solution (duplicate) doesn't actually work.

```
\documentclass[aps,prc,reprint,superscriptaddress,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[pdftex, demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!80!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[]
    \centering
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_2n.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_2n}
        }\hfil
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_2n_m2.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_2n_m2}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_3n.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_3n}
        }\hfil
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_p.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_p}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_alpha.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_alpha}
        }\hfil
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_el.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_el}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_tot.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_tot}
        }\hfil
    %\end{subfigure}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4555\textwidth}
      \caption{Blah blah blah}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Using `\fbox` one can even show that the resulting minipage is totally empty.

Comment: You can also put a caption into a \floatbox and it will not be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that floatrow modifies `\@makecaption` to convert the caption into a global macro or savebox, which it then positions elsewhere.

```
\documentclass[aps,prc,reprint,superscriptaddress,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\let\old@makecaption=\@makecaption% still gets intercepted
\makeatother
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[pdftex, demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!80!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[]
    \centering
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_2n.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_2n}
        }\hfil
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_2n_m2.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_2n_m2}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_3n.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_3n}
        }\hfil
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_p.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_p}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_alpha.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_alpha}
        }\hfil
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_el.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_el}
        }\\
    %\end{subfigure}
    %\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        %\centering
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{CS_tot.png}
        %\caption{}
        \label{fig:CS_tot}
        }\hfil
    %\end{subfigure}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4555\textwidth}
      \makeatletter
      \let\@makecaption=\old@makecaption
      \makeatother
      \caption{Blah blah blah}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```