# Vertical alignment of table and figure placed side-by-side in two-column mode

Tags: vertical-alignment, floatrow

I'm using IEEE's spconf.sty file to create a two-column document. I am placing a table with its caption above and a figure with two subfigures with their captions below side-by-side using the floatrow package. I want the bottom of the table to align with the bottom of the caption. The command `\BottomFloatBoxes` aligns the bottom of the table with the top of the figure caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}   % for placing table and figure side-by-side

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}\BottomFloatBoxes
\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox[0.75\Xhsize]
  {\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}%
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Linear} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{RBF} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Polynomial} \\
    \midrule
    $C$   & $\gamma$ & Accuracy (\%) & $C$   & $\gamma$ & Accuracy (\%) & $d$   & $\gamma$ & Accuracy (\%) \\
    \midrule
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}%
    {\caption{Classification results for different SVM kernels}
    \label{tab:results}}%
    \killfloatstyle\ffigbox[\Xhsize]
    {\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[0.5\Xhsize]
    {\caption{}
    \label{fig:models:subfig:good}}
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{box.png}}
    \ffigbox[\Xhsize]
    {\caption{}
    \label{fig:models:subfig:bad}}
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{box.png}}
    \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{Examples of models. \ref{fig:models:subfig:good} is predicted as `good' and \ref{fig:models:subfig:bad} is predicted as `bad'.}
    \label{fig:models}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure*}%
\end{document}
```

Using the above MWE gives me the following output:

[image]

For someone who wants to reproduce this MWE, the style file spconf.sty can be found [here](https://2018.ieeeicip.org/Papers/PaperFormat/spconf.sty).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid floatrow if possible.  Also, I couldn't find spfconf.sty.  Getting the figure counter right was a bit of a kludge.  Note: you can use `\subref` and lose the figure number.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \sbox0{\begin{tabular}[b]{ccccccccc}%
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Linear} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{RBF} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Polynomial} \\
    \midrule
    $C$   & $\gamma$ & Accuracy (\%) & $C$   & $\gamma$ & Accuracy (\%) & $d$   & $\gamma$ & Accuracy (\%) \\
    \midrule
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\wd0}
    \captionof{table}{Classification results for different SVM kernels}
    \label{tab:results}%
    \usebox0
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0-\columnsep}
    \stepcounter{figure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{fig:models:subfig:good}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{fig:models:subfig:bad}
    \end{subfigure}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
    \caption{Examples of models. \ref{fig:models:subfig:good} is predicted as `good' and \ref{fig:models:subfig:bad} is predicted as `bad'.}
     \label{fig:models}%
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}%
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Why do you not recommend `floatrow`?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?s=4|30.8184