# Could a caption takes place of a subfig?

Tags: floats, captions, subfig

[image]

As shown above, how to make the caption takes place of the top-right subfig?
Is this possible? Then, can the refering of this caption works?

Comment: Just put the caption inside a minipage.  Unless you are using floatrow package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?s=4|25.8384)

Answer (score 7):

You can just arrange the images using a `tabular` and put the caption in one of the cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{m{4cm}m{4cm}}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \caption{Top to bottom: hazy image: Forest and some more text to fill this cell up further} \\
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]