# Floatrow: \floatbox for single element floats

Tags: floatrow

Is the use of `\floatbox` (`\ffbox`, `\ttbox`, ...) required in single element float enviornments? While the documentation of [floatrow](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf) uses it in all its examples, I can't tell a difference between an image, with and without the `\ffbox` wrapper. Are there any reason to use the wrapper, if the float environment contains just a single element?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=Ruled}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \ffigbox{ % Is this unneccessary verbosity? Or does it do some magic I miss?
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{A}
        }{}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        \caption{B}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is the documentation outdated, afterall it states that the two arguments of the macros that separate content and caption exist for historical reasons and it does not matter how you distribute your content between the too. Is it possible, that the examples in the documentation have not been updated since the second argument becam obsolete?

Comment: It makes a difference if you use [\FBwidth].  The real question is whether there is any point in using floatrow.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: After reading [this thread](https://golatex.de/subfig-vs-subcaption-floatrow-etc-t4226.html) (german), I thought that floatrow, while complex, is the most powerfull solution for subfigures. I quite like the global setup of caption positions and float styles. Appart from its supposed complexity, are there reasons to NOT use floatrow?

Comment: Aside from it not doing anything you can't do yourself, it often does things you don't want it to do.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?s=4|25.9810