# above- and belowcaptionskip with Floatrow package

Tags: floats, captions, floatrow

Is it possible to force the `floatrow` package to take into account the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`?

Even if I (re)define these two lengths after `\usepackage{floatrow}`, they are not taken into account.

The documentation is rather evasive on this subject...
The only thing I found is the keyword `captionskip`, but even when I set `captionskip` to be equal to `abovecaptionskip`, the result is not visually the same ; I don't know how it works exactly.
And I haven't found an equivalent to `belowcaptionskip`.

[image]

So is it possible to force `floatrow` to use the `above`- and `belowcaptionskip` values defined either by the documentclass or directly by the user?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum, mwe}

\setlength\abovecaptionskip{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{2pt plus 2pt minus 0pt}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup{captionskip=12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width =.5\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{The caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For a figure, for which the caption is *below* the figure, you only need `\abovecaptionskip`; `\belowcaptionskip` would only add a spurious vertical spacing to the normal `\intextsep` added by the figure environment. Compiling your code produces indeed a 12pt spacing between image and caption (measured on screen).

Comment: Since floatrow use a picture environment to place everything, it probably doesn't pay any attention to \vspace.  Plus it uses a custom caption.

Comment: @Bernard I have not measured, but I don't get the same result with or without the `floatrow` package (see the picture I added).  I give `belowcaptionskip` a non-zero value because I find that slightly increasing the space between the caption and the text is visually more beautiful.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I didn't know `floatrow` was using a `picture` environment. I find this a bit surprising, but it explains why it doesn't take `above-` and `belowcaptionskip` into account.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?r=SearchResults&s=2|42.0579