# Subfigure caption placement incorrect

Tags: captions, subcaption

No matter how many packages I remove, I can't seem to find out why the captions on my subfigures are being placed on top of the figures rather than below. I've stripped away everything in my document but the bare essentials, but the captions are still placed on top, despite my code being identical to that of people who do not experience the issue. What in the world is up? How do I force the subcaptions below the images, as is standard?[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\pdfoutput=1

\usepackage{graphicx} % Including graphics

\usepackage{subcaption} % For subfigures

\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
%\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \caption{Test.
    \label{fig:StNDdbL}}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{2ex}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \caption{Test.
    \label{fig:StNDdbP}}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]

%\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \caption{Test.
    \label{fig:StNFbpL}}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{2ex}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \caption{Test.
    \label{fig:StNFbpP}}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Test.
\label{fig:StImages}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to put the caption literally below the graphic in the code.

Comment: It's actually sensitive to that?! Perhaps I've been spending too much time filling out bibtex files where such a thing doesn't matter.... Wow, thanks.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comment:

Put the `\caption{}` below the graphic in the code. Like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\pdfoutput=1

\usepackage{graphicx} % Including graphics

\usepackage{subcaption} % For subfigures

\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=bottom}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[t]
        %\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            %\centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Test.
                \label{fig:StNDdbL}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace{2ex}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            %\centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Test.
                \label{fig:StNDdbP}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \\[3ex]
        
        %\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            %\centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Test.
                \label{fig:StNFbpL}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace{2ex}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            %\centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Test.
                \label{fig:StNFbpP}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Test.
            \label{fig:StImages}}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, thank you. It never even crossed my mind that the creators would make the order of the arguments relevant.