# How to add a separate caption for each sub-figure?

Tags: minipage, overleaf, includegraphics

How can I have a single caption above both figures, with two separate distinct captions above each?

I also want to make it count as two figures and not as a single one as it is right now.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
 \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
\footnotesize
\color{black}}
\makeatother
\copyrightbox [b] {
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    \caption{Time evolution for lending}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{time evolution lending.png}
    \label{img1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \caption{Countries in the lending dataset}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Lending Map Subset.pdf}
    \label{img2}
\end{minipage}
}{source: illustrations created with the software r}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: The `floatrow` package and its eponymous environment are done for that.

Comment: Just use two `\caption` macros inside your `minipage`s.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for your comment. I've tried it but unfortunately it didn't help. The only thing that changed was that now I have two different figures in the my list of figures (good! I wanted to have this) but I still get exactly the same picture of the figures as posted in my question. For some reason, latex only displays the second caption over both figures although I have a caption for each figure in my code. I edited the code in ma question to show the current one.

Comment: Perhaps compile again? I get the two caption as you want, using your code.

Comment: Certain packages move the caption around (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C29.8826)  What package does package does \copyrightbox come from?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I inserted \usepackage{copyrightbox} in the preamble to be able to use  \copyrightbox.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, you're right. After deleting \usepackage{floatrow} in my preamble, both captions are correctly displayed. Thanks for your support. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW, copyrightbox uses tikz, so putting a tikzpicture inside will result in nested tikzpictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a common caption for both figures AS WELL AS a separate sub-caption for each figure, you might be interested in the appropriately named `subcaption` package. You can use it to treat both images as subfigures of the same figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Time evolution for lending and countries in the leading dataset}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \caption{Time evolution for lending}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{img1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \caption{Countries in the lending dataset}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \label{img2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \label{img1&2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of subfigure]

Subcaption has some formatting options to make your life easier. For example, sufigure environment accepts an b/c/t arguments, which align the graphics vertically to the bottom/center/top, respectively.