# Width of a caption at left side of the table

Tags: tables, captions, overleaf, sidecap

How to make the title of a table fit the width of the left side?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim} %comments
\usepackage{lipsum,capt-of,graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\let\printorcid\relax
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=period, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=footnotesize, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}%,skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\sffamily}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx, multirow}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[table]{captionskip=0.1pt}
\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{placeins}

\sisetup{
  print-unity-mantissa=false,
  retain-zero-uncertainty=true,
}
\setlength\emergencystretch{3em}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.75\textwidth}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=3cm}}]{table}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{Performance comparison of the proposed method with the other works.}\label{fig:test}}
{
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
Alpha1 & Alpha2 & Alpha3 & Alpha4 & Alpha5 & Alpha6 \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(rl){2-6} 
asfafssadcffaf sdfaaasd dsdsfsfsf. [1] \cite{} & 
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} \\

asfafssadcffaf sdfaaasd dsdsfsfsf. [1] \cite{} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} \\

asfafssadcffaf sdfaaasd dsdsfsfsf. [1] \cite{} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} \\


asfafssadcffaf sdfaaasd dsdsfsfsf. [1] \cite{} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} \\


asfafssadcffaf sdfaaasd dsdsfsfsf. [1] \cite{} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} \\

asfafsffdcasdaf sdfaaasd dsdsfsdfsf. [1] \cite{} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} &
\num{78.57 \pm 4.41} \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use floatrow?  Adding captions to the side is no big deal (if there is enough room).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: It seems that there is enough space. But, what is the problem with the floatrow?

Comment: It has harmful side effects and is difficult to work with.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption for example.