# Caption Always Below Figure

Tags: captions, positioning

I'm using the [LaTeX Thesis Template](https://www.matthiaspospiech.de/latex/templates/thesis/) by Matthias Pospiech and regardless of what I try - `captionbeside`, `minipages`, etc. -, LaTeX always places the caption *below* the figure. But I want them beside the figure for some figures.

I failed to reproduce the issue with a MWE. Does anyone has a guess what might be the cause? I'm getting nuts. It still persists if I comment all settings related to `floatrow` and `caption`.

#### Some examples

Plain:

```latex
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.}
\end{figure}
```

[image: plain]

```tex
\begin{figure}
    \begin{captionbeside}{Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.}[o]
        \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
```

[image: captionbeside]

```tex
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \mbox{}\\[-\baselineskip]
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}~\hfill~%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.38\textwidth}
        \mbox{}\\[-\baselineskip]
        \caption{Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image: minipage]
Thanks a lot!

Comment: well the template doesn't compile for me. But beside this:  that is the problem with such overloaded templates. There are tons of packages and settings and finding where it fails cost lots of time.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm totally with you and I'm not gonna fall for it again. If it works, it's gold, if it fails, your doomed. For this one, I don't know whether I have the time left to re-create everything from the scratch ... **P.S.** To make it compile: **(1)** Kick `tocstyle` in `packages.tex` and `style.tex` **(2)** Kick `\usetkzobj{all}` and move `tkz-fct` in-front of `tkz-euclide` in `packages-tikzpgf.tex` **(3)** on l.25: `\NewDocumentCommand\unit{om}{%` to `\RenewDocumentCommand\unit{om}{%`.

Comment: LaTeX places the caption where you put it, but some packages (floatrow and float) move the caption around.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption/403662?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C45.2691#403662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the example based on `minipage`. From the snippets I understand you prefer the top alignment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}  % For filler text
\usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{belowlabel}{#1#2}
    \captionsetup[figure]{
        format=belowlabel,
        position=top,
        singlelinecheck=false,
        skip=6pt,
    }


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=T]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-1em}
        \caption{\null}
        
        \RaggedRight Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\kant[2][1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT.
If this style must e intervened with a normal style, `\captionseup` needs to be inside an environment to make changes of local scope. The whole style can be enclosed in a macro:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{O{} m m}{%
  \begin{figure}[#1]
    \captionsetup{
      format=belowlabel,
      position=top,
      singlelinecheck=false,
      skip=6pt,
    }
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=T]{#2}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-1em}
      \caption{\null}
      \IfValueT{#3}{\notblank{#3}{\par\RaggedRight #3}{}}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}}
```

Other images will follow the standard style. See the updated code and a screenshot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}  % For filler text
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{belowlabel}{#1#2}

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{O{} m m}{%
  \begin{figure}[#1]
    \captionsetup{
      format=belowlabel,
      position=top,
      singlelinecheck=false,
      skip=6pt,
    }
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=T]{#2}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-1em}
      \caption{\null}
      \IfValueT{#3}{\notblank{#3}{\par\RaggedRight #3}{}}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\Figure[tbh]{example-image}{%
  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
  Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.
  Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
  Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.}

\kant[1][2]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth,valign=T]{example-image}
  \caption{%
    Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
    Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.
    Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
    Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][3]

\Figure{example-image-a}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's certainly a nice way to do it but don't want to change the style globally. I will not touch this template again but for now, I'll stick to it. And thank you for the `kantlipsum` package! :D I didn't know about that one.

Comment: `\captionseup` can be moved inside environments and affect only such environments. Other images will keep the standard style. A good approach is to make a wrapper with  a couple of parameters (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Celdor's answer I'd like to add a second, more down to earth,  way for anyone else struggling with this using the aforementioned template: The template uses the `floatrow` package and one can change the style locally by using braces. E.g.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{microtype,graphicx,floatrow,caption,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

{
    \floatsetup[figure]
    {style=plain,capposition=beside,objectset=centering,
    capbesidewidth=.5\textwidth,capbesideposition=outside,
    floatwidth=sidefil}
    \captionsetup[figure]{format=plain}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \caption{\kant[1][1]}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \caption{\kant[1][1]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: rendered_code]