# Insert Figure caption in a table element

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I have a table with an odd number of pictures that I dispose two per row. The bottom-right corner is then figure-less, and I would like that the caption of the figure appears there to save some vertical space. It should really be the caption, so that I can reference the figure in the text if needed.

Is there a solution?

Example:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figures/test}
     & 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figures/test}
    \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figures/test}
    & 
    PUT FIGURE WITH CAPTION HERE (to be referred)
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you are using floatrow (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C42.3489).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column type `p`, `m` or `b`. `m` and `b` need [package `array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array), which is also useful for centering the images inside the columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b{.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
     & 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
    \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c}
    & 
    \caption{PUT FIGURE WITH CAPTION HERE (to be referred)}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: bottom aligned caption]

The three column types only differ in the vertical alignment. Sometimes using [package `adjustbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) could also be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
     & 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
    \\
    \adjincludegraphics[scale=0.5,valign=T]{example-image-c}
    & 
    \caption{PUT FIGURE WITH CAPTION HERE (to be referred)}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: top aligned caption]

Comment: Does this conflict with booktabs?

Comment: @G.Gare Don't think so. But if you have a problem in combination with `booktabs` please ask a new question with a corresponding [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) instead of a code snippet only.

Comment: Fair enough. It actually doesn't. I made it work using your solution.

Comment: The label to the figure should be added within tabular (just below the caption) and not in the figure outside the tabular - for completeness