# With `floatrow`, how to put a caption in the first row of the table?

Tags: captions, tcolorbox, nicematrix, floatrow, captionof

I have a big project were the package `floatrow` are used.
I discovered that when this package are used, the caption put inside my tables are now show outside.
I can't find any way of getting it back inside.

Here is my MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article} % Document class
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks
\usepackage{siunitx} % For typesetting numbers and units
\usepackage{nicematrix} % For creating tables
\usepackage{caption} % For customizing captions
\usepackage{xcolor} % For custom colors
\usepackage{floatrow} % For customizing float environments

%%% Color definition
\definecolor{gray-100}{HTML}{f3f4f6}
\definecolor{gray-200}{HTML}{e5e7eb}
\definecolor{gray-600}{HTML}{4b5563}
\definecolor{gray-800}{HTML}{1f2937}
\definecolor{slate-50}{HTML}{f8fafc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
   \centering % Center the table
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Adjust row height
\captionsetup[table]{font={bf,sf,color=gray-600,small}, skip=0pt} % Customize table caption
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcS}[hvlines, rounded-corners=6pt, rules/color=gray-200] % Create NiceTabular with specified properties
\CodeBefore % LaTeX code before the table
\rowcolor{gray-100}{1-2} % Colorize the first row
   \rowcolors{3}{}{slate-50} % Alternate row colors starting from the third row
\Body % Body of the table
   \Block{1-3}{\begin{minipage}{50mm}\captionof{table}{Table Title 1}\label{tab:title1}\end{minipage}} \\ % Multi-column cell for caption
   \RowStyle[bold]{\color{gray-600}} % Style for the first data row
    Town & Correspondant & {Value} \\ % Table headers
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=*,color=gray-800]{} % Style for the remaining data rows
    Paris & Peter & 1.23 \\ % Data rows
    London & Helena & 23.23\\
    Madrid & Georges &12.5 \\
    Moscou & Henry & 4.77 \\
    Tokyo & Selena & 85.3 \\
    Lima & Victoria & 13.2 \\
    Cap Town & Alexandra & 6 \\
    Chicago & Vladimier & 1.34
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I use NiceTabular, but I am also able to get the same issue using `tcolorbox`.

The expected result:

[image: Expected result, where caption are on the first row]

Actual:

[image: Actual result with floatrow package: the caption is outside the table]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C31.0909

Comment: @JohnKormylo already check. Does not solve my probllem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the `\captionof` in `floatrow` command `\RawCaption` does the trick:

```tex
\RawCaption{\captionof{table}{Table Title 1}\label{tab:title1}}
```

From `floatrow`'s package manual (v0.3b, 2009-08-02), sec. 2.4.1 "Raw Caption—Printing in Unusual Way"

> `\RawCaption`
>
> This command allows to “release” caption contents from special box register created by `floatrow` package for the creation of necessary layout. The caption is placed as argument of `\RawCaption`:
>
> ```
> \RawCaption{\caption\marg{contents}\label{...}}` .
> ```

```tex
\documentclass{article} % Document class
\usepackage{siunitx} % For typesetting numbers and units
\usepackage{nicematrix} % For creating tables
\usepackage{caption} % For customizing captions
\usepackage{xcolor} % For custom colors
\usepackage{floatrow} % For customizing float environments

\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks; load hyperref last

%%% Color definition
\definecolor{gray-100}{HTML}{f3f4f6}
\definecolor{gray-200}{HTML}{e5e7eb}
\definecolor{gray-600}{HTML}{4b5563}
\definecolor{gray-800}{HTML}{1f2937}
\definecolor{slate-50}{HTML}{f8fafc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
   \centering % Center the table
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Adjust row height
\captionsetup[table]{font={bf,sf,color=gray-600,small}, skip=0pt} % Customize table caption
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcS}[hvlines, rounded-corners=6pt, rules/color=gray-200] % Create NiceTabular with specified properties
\CodeBefore % LaTeX code before the table
\rowcolor{gray-100}{1-2} % Colorize the first row
   \rowcolors{3}{}{slate-50} % Alternate row colors starting from the third row
\Body % Body of the table
   \Block{1-3}{%
    \begin{minipage}{50mm}
      \RawCaption{\captionof{table}{Table Title 1}\label{tab:title1}}
    \end{minipage}} \\ % Multi-column cell for caption
   \RowStyle[bold]{\color{gray-600}} % Style for the first data row
    Town & Correspondant & {Value} \\ % Table headers
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=*,color=gray-800]{} % Style for the remaining data rows
    Paris & Peter & 1.23 \\ % Data rows
    London & Helena & 23.23\\
    Madrid & Georges &12.5 \\
    Moscou & Henry & 4.77 \\
    Tokyo & Selena & 85.3 \\
    Lima & Victoria & 13.2 \\
    Cap Town & Alexandra & 6 \\
    Chicago & Vladimier & 1.34
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you   it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The basic principle works, although in this case you aren't putting the caption inside a minipage.  OTOH, `\RawCaption` was added to floatrow specifically to handle this problem.

```
\documentclass{article} % Document class
\makeatletter
  \let\old@makecaption=\@makecaption
\makeatother
\usepackage{siunitx} % For typesetting numbers and units
\usepackage{nicematrix} % For creating tables
\usepackage{caption} % For customizing captions
\usepackage{xcolor} % For custom colors
\usepackage{floatrow} % For customizing float environments
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks

%%% Color definition
\definecolor{gray-100}{HTML}{f3f4f6}
\definecolor{gray-200}{HTML}{e5e7eb}
\definecolor{gray-600}{HTML}{4b5563}
\definecolor{gray-800}{HTML}{1f2937}
\definecolor{slate-50}{HTML}{f8fafc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\makeatletter
  \let\@makecaption=\old@makecaption
\makeatother
\centering % Center the table
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Adjust row height
\captionsetup[table]{font={bf,sf,color=gray-600,small}, skip=0pt} % Customize table caption
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcS}[hvlines, rounded-corners=6pt, rules/color=gray-200] % Create NiceTabular with specified properties
\CodeBefore % LaTeX code before the table
\rowcolor{gray-100}{1-2} % Colorize the first row
   \rowcolors{3}{}{slate-50} % Alternate row colors starting from the third row
\Body % Body of the table
   \Block{1-3}{\begin{minipage}{50mm}\captionof{table}{Table Title 1}\label{tab:title1}\end{minipage}} \\ % Multi-column cell for caption
   \RowStyle[bold]{\color{gray-600}} % Style for the first data row
    Town & Correspondant & {Value} \\ % Table headers
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=*,color=gray-800]{} % Style for the remaining data rows
    Paris & Peter & 1.23 \\ % Data rows
    London & Helena & 23.23\\
    Madrid & Georges &12.5 \\
    Moscou & Henry & 4.77 \\
    Tokyo & Selena & 85.3 \\
    Lima & Victoria & 13.2 \\
    Cap Town & Alexandra & 6 \\
    Chicago & Vladimier & 1.34
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```